# my git pre-commit hook is not executing Astyle, and isnt setting variables. why?

Tags: git, githooks, pre-commit

IM writting a simple git pre-commit hook to run Astyle (a code beautifier) in the files that are going to be commited. Here is the code:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "git diff:" 
FICHEROS=`git diff --name-only`
if [ -z "${FICHEROS}" ]; then
  echo "Files not found"
else
  echo "files are:"
  echo "$FICHEROS" 
  cp $FICHEROS ${FICHEROS}_copy
  echo "Running astyle"
  /home/robgon/astyle/build/gcc/bin/astyle --indent=force-tab --pad-oper --pad-paren --delete-empty-lines --suffix=none --indent-namespaces --indent-col1-comments -n ${FICHEROS}_copy
  echo "Formatted"
fi
```

When I try to commit a file, named "file1.c" with a git commit -a -m "test1", for example, I get in the console:

```
git diff:
Files not found
[master d3d2526] test1
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
```

So, the git diff --name-only is not setting the output in FICHEROS. If the pre-commit only try to run astyle, the script skips the output and doesnt format the file...

If i run the .git/hooks/pre-commit from my console I get:

```
git diff:
files are:
file1.c
Running astyle
Formato     /home/robgon/gitTuto/gitRepo1/proj/file1.c_copy
Formatted
```

Why git cant execute astyle and set variables in the pre-commit script, and when i run the pre-commit from my console, it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to do `git diff` against what is about to be committed by using `--cached`:

```
FICHEROS=`git diff --cached --name-only`
```

Comment: if I run git diff --cached --name-only, I dont have any output in console (running this command in my own console). And the script throws the same output. :(

Comment: What if you run `git status` in the hook script?

Comment: if I run git status in the beginning of the script it works!! thanks you! I need to investigate why I need the git status to run the git diff later. Im a newbie in Git

Comment: I'm pretty sure running git status didn't actually fix it.  Anyway, good luck!

Comment: maybe is there another change that fix the set Var and the run astyle. Here is the full script (its only a example script to format the file in other file before commit it)

Answer (score 2):

Here is the new script, it runs now:

```
!/bin/sh
echo `git status`
echo "git diff:" 
FICHEROS=`git diff --cached --name-only`
if [ -z "${FICHEROS}" ]; then
  echo "Files not found"
else
  echo "files are:"
  echo "$FICHEROS" 
  cp $FICHEROS ${FICHEROS}_copy
  echo "Running astyle"
  /home/robgon/astyle/build/gcc/bin/astyle --indent=force-tab --pad-oper --pad-paren --delete-empty-lines --suffix=none --indent-namespaces --indent-col1-comments -n ${FICHEROS}_copy
  echo "Formatted"
fi
```